# Difference between style of passing functions

Tags: javascript, react-native

What is the difference between these function calling styles?

```
onPress = { () => { this.myFunctions() } }
```

And

```
onPress = { this.myFunctions() }
```

Comment: The 2nd one is incorrect (should be without parens). Read the explanation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

Comment: @Raptor That significantly changes the question. There is nothing ambiguous about what the question asker has asked. It is not incorrect in any way.

Comment: @MattWay with parens, `myFunctions` is called instead of passed as a reference, which is not the suggested behavior of React Native.

Comment: @Raptor I understand what the code above does. What I am saying is that it is perfectly valid, as is the question. There is no 'suggested behaviour' in this case. What you are saying changes the question significantly.

Comment: I didn't intend to change the question, just pointing out with / without parens mean total different things (though the behavior is the same)

Comment: use onPress={this.myFunctions} my friends?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onPress={() =>{this.myFunctions()}}`

You are passing an anonymous function which after onPress was invoked would call `this.myFunctions()`

`onPress={this.myFunctions()}`

You are passing into onPress the return value of `this.myFunctions` which means this gets executed everytime render is invoked by the component.

Both of the above ways of passing function into a `React` component are not advisable performance-wise. Using the above methods causes the function with the onPress to rerender everytime the parent renders because as it does a shallow comparison of previous anonymous function declaration it will result in two function not being equal as it is compared by reference.

It is advised to use below:

`onPress={this.myFunctions}`

where you are passing the reference of the function `myFunctions`. And whenever the parent rerenders, once the component has checked if new myFunctions is the same with previous render, it will return as true and will not render again the child.

Comment: constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }
certain effects to call func ?

Comment: I don't get what you mean @NguyễnTuấnVũ .

Answer (score 1):

You can use both

```js
onPress={() =>{this.myFunctions()}}
//and
onPress={this.myFunctions} // without ()
```

If you want to pass arguments, you should use first one.

```js
onPress={(e) =>{this.myFunctions(id, e)}}
```

Comment: Correct. In fact, `onPress={this.myFunctions}` is different from `onPress={this.myFunctions()}`. Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks you. Yes. I know it, I want get more case from you bro.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge difference here.

```
onPress={this.myFunctions()}
```

The usage above means to **evaluate** the result of `myFunctions` and use the *result* in on press. This would only make sense if `myFunctions()` returned another function.

```
onPress={() =>{this.myFunctions()}}
```

The above means when `onPress` is triggered, **then** `myFunctions` is ran.

Comment: should be use onPress={() =>{this.myFunctions()}} because I use onPress={this.myFunctions} is always call when start app ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no real difference as long as it's just one function - although without the `()` (parentheses) in your second approach:

```
onPress={this.myFunctions}
```

If you want arguments:

```
onPress={e => this.myFunctions(e)}
```